# Debian login prompt appears while system is still starting up

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi

Please see the attached screenshot for the problem.

The Linux kernel output is still being shown after the Getty login screen has appeared. I've not known this to happen before in any other installs, so I must have a bad config somewhere.

This is my own Debootstrapped distro on a Raspberry Pi.

[image]

Comment: It does seem odd that it takes somewhere over 20 seconds to initialize your keyboard.  What "other installs" do you have in mind? - list the most similar ones.  Please, could you link a more useful kernel log (`dmesg > log.txt`, upload to a reliable cloud file-share).

Comment: That was just me plugging in the wireless keyboard 20 seconds after startup so I could login :)

Comment: Ok.  Is it possible to compare `cat /proc/cmdline` v.s. "other installs"?  (hint: it sounds like you want the kernel to be `quiet`).  It's set by the bootloader, I don't know how that is configured on the PI.

Comment: You are using a multitasking operating system.  Seeing it still doing stuff (such as initializing the PRNG) whilst it is presenting the initial login prompt on a terminal should not be cause to immediately leap to the conclusion that it is wrongly configured.

Answer (score 0):

The messages are for hotplug.

You can request an old-style full coldplug for hotpluggable devices, using `systemctl enable systemd-udev-settle`.  This will not solve the 20s+ delay, but it might re-order the events as you requested :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This does not seem to work, after a reboot I am still getting the messages appearing after the login screen shows. Also, hotplug messages seem to be shown as well. I am not sure whether it is just hotplug messages shown?